# Get all file/img input fields from a form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Seems like such a novice question but I'm stuck.  I have a form in which user can dynamically add rows of `<input...` and select images to be added inside a textarea.  Upon submitting, I'm trying to select all rows with images.

```
<input type="file" class="pics" name="file[]" onchange="imgChanged(this)"><img class="addImg" onclick="addRow(this)" src="../img/addmore.png">
```

So there's a possibility of "n" number of images.  The inputs have the class of "pics".  How can I get them all before uploading using the `new FormData` in JS?  I can't seem to get it like this...

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("pics").files
```

And then use it like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var file = imgs[i];
    formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
}
```

Hope this is an easy solutions.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to getElementById would work. Refer the example at end here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Each input field will have the same id?  I thought that was a big no-no

Comment: Ah I see. I think your best bet is to loop through `document.getElementsByClassName("pics")` and append the `files` for each element.